# Extending doctrine:build --db to create a DB View

Tags: php, symfony1, view, doctrine, dbal

I'm working on a Symfony 1.4 project with Doctrine 1.x, and functionality that merits using a Doctrie_View (as an interface for native MySQL Views).

As I understand it, the View (as in DB View as opposed to the View in MVC) has to be created wth Doctrine so that Doctrine can maintain the association between the View and the original Model from which it's derived.

In an ideal world, I'd like to have the View created as part of the `symfony doctrine:build --db` task. The sensible way to do this would be to use the observer pattern and Symfony's Event Dispatcher, however, the list of [Built In-Events](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/17-Extending-Symfony#chapter_17_sub_built_in_events) doesn't seem to offer an event for when the database schema is built.

So, what's the best way to have a Doctrine View created when the schema is built?

Or perhaps, if that's not an option, check if a View doesn't exist and then create it as part of `ProjectConfiguration::configureDoctrine()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**doctrine:build-sql**

I think you should rather look at the *doctrine:build-sql* task which builds the sql instructions from the model definition.

If you look at the *sfDoctrineBuildSqlTask* class you'll notice it's rather simple. It really only calls the doctrine cli. If you want to hook into it you should check the **Doctrine events** rather than symfony.

**migrations**

What you could also do is creating your view in doctrine migrations. Whenever you need to change your view you'll create another migration (removing old and creating new view).

Comment: Hadn't thought about doing it with migrations, nice idea!